# Spring Boot Maven Plugin - Define working directory

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm working on a spring boot app version 1.3.5.RELEASE and I'm trying to implement integration test using the spring-boot-maven-plugin (using start/stop goals). My application.properties file is currently in the target/test folder, but when running it, the app is looking for the application.properties file in the root path of the project.

Does anyone know how to set the working directory in the spring boot maven plugin?

My current plugin configuration is:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>o.m.e.Application</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: what is the unit testing framework you are using? jUnit or testNg ?

Comment: You don't have to do this so complicated but can ask Spring Boot to create the necessary context using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` or `SpringRunner` if using Spring Boot 1.4.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate Karma test runner to fully test my UI with real server data. Maven is calling Karma using frontend-maven-plugin in the integration-test. All I have to do is to have the app started and stopped before and after the integration-test.

Comment: +daniel, I'm already using it for unit tests and it's working pretty well, but now I'm trying to integrate the UI tests with real server data.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the test-property source path as follows.

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
```

add this annotation to the Unit test class being developed.

e.g:-

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = XXXXXXX.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath: XXXXXXX.properties")
public class AppCoreGenericTests{

   //unit tests should go here 
}
```